# Display Related list records through visualforce page.

Tags: visualforce

I have this Account object, for the respective object we have one Activity History Related list.

I need to display the Activity history for Account object through VisualForce Page.

How can it be Achieve? i want to display same record into the visual force page.
 [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can display the related list in a VF page using **apex:relatedList** tag.
Following is the visualforce code to display Activity History:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:relatedList list="ActivityHistories" title="Activity History" />
</apex:page>
```

Below is the output:

[image]

You can refer this link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_relatedList.htm

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hi Ankita, it is displaying nothing for me, though i have one record for Activity History for Account.

Comment: You need to pass the account Id in this way:
For example, if 001D000000IRt53 is the account ID, the resulting URL should be:
https://Salesforce_instance/apex/myPage?id=001D000000IRt53

Comment: oh yes, it worked thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use **apex:relatedList** tag

```
 <apex:relatedList title="Activity History"  list="ActivityHistories" />
```